# How to use SentimentAnalysis package in R? what i the meaning of GI, ME, and LM?

Tags: r, sentiment-analysis

Can anyone explain the meaning of GI, HE, LM, QDAP in the SentimentAnalysis package in R? What is the best way to identify the polarity of a sentence using this package given that it gives multiple answers if we look at each of these above-mentioned columns?

Answer (score 0):

It is better to have somebody with domain knowledge to deepen your understanding on NLP (Natural Language Processing), Sentiment Analysis, and along with it all its terminologies.

You can also read up the docs for SentimentAnalysis package at https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/SentimentAnalysis/SentimentAnalysis.pdf. **GI** for example is **General Inquirer** and is a Harvard-IV dictionary. It is one of many dictionaries available in SentimentAnalysis package. Usually in realm of sentiment analysis, these dictionaries provide a list of words that are considered positive or negative. Some dictionaries can even provide scoring to rate how positive or negative a word is. Please read up this doc first to ask more specific question.

One way to identify polarity of a sentence is that to collect all words with sentiment and average out the sentiments (for example, in 1 sentence there 3 positive and 2 negative sentiments, we can regard this sentence to have overall positive sentiment). This is just a basic method to analyze sentiments within a sentence. Natural language is very complex, of course you have to see the context when analyzing a sentiment (Ex: "I am not sad" has positive sentiment due to the negation term "*not*" despite having word which is considered negative ie. "*sad*").